# output from a bash command in a variable is wrapped in apostrophes. Why?

Tags: bash

bash noob here. I have a bash command that if I execute as normal from the command line returns an ip address:

`kubectl get svc ssdl-web --namespace default -o jsonpath='{$.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'`

returns:

> 104.76.131.131

However if I store the command in a var and then execute it the answer comes back wrapped in apostrophes:

`get_external_ip_cmd="kubectl get svc ssdl-web --namespace default -o jsonpath='{$.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'" && echo $($(echo $get_external_ip_cmd))`

> '104.76.131.131'

I need the result without the apostrophes.

I'm sure there's a simple explanation but I haven't a clue what. Can anyone fill me in? thx.

*(My reason for storing the command in a var is that I want to execute it multiple times)*

Comment: Don't store shell commands in string variables -- use functions for that. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Only a small subset of shell parsing steps are run on parameter expansion or command substitution results (for good reason; there would be massive security vulnerabilities in shell languages if referring to variables containing data, or commands generating data as their output, parsed that data as code).

Comment: fair enough. will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitution results only go through string-splitting and glob-expansion. They *don't* go through quote removal (quotes are treated as literal, not syntactic), so the quotes are passed to your command rather than consumed by the shell.

This is discussed in detail in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Best practice is generally to use functions, not strings, to store code intended to be called multiple times. (In some circumstances arrays may be more appropriate instead; read the FAQ for details).

---

Defining a function with your code looks like:

```
get_external_ip() {
  kubectl get svc ssdl-web \
    --namespace default \
    -o jsonpath='{$.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'
}
```

Then run it as:

```
get_external_ip
```